# Batch file for loop directory search result changes when clicking on the batch file versus dragging a folder onto the batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

**Problem statement:** Dragging a folder onto a batch file changes the result of a for loop while simply clicking on the batch file results in different but desired output from the mentioned for loop.

**Background:**
I would like to retrieve the latest created .jar file's name in a folder. A .bat file will be located in this folder where the .jars are. With the example .bat file code provided below, I double click the .bat file and get the result that I am looking for e.g. : {jar_root_dir_path}+"logger-20191030.jar", see the *"Desired output:"* section below for clarification.

Thing is that this .bat file will only be used in the case where someone would drag a folder onto it and then pass this information to the .jar file. This is where my problem comes in. When I drag a folder onto the batch file, I do not get any file results for the latest .jar file. Refer to the *"Current output:"* section below to see the output of the problem.

**Code:**

```
#Example code 

@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /b logger*.jar') do set latestjar=%%x
echo "%~dp0%latestjar%" + "%~dp0output.txt"
pause
```

**Output:**

***Note:*** {example_path_here} in this question only acts as a placeholder for actual directory / file paths e.g. {example_dir} = "D:\Installation\Logger\"

*Current output:*

```
File Not Found
{root_directory_of_.bat} + {root_directory_of_.bat_with_output_file_name_appended}
Press any key to continue . . .
```

*Desired output:*

```
{root_directory_of_.bat_with_latest_.jar_file_appended} + {root_directory_of_.bat_with_output_file_name_appended}
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After analysis the following was determined:**

1. A double click event will let the execution take place in the current folder where the .bat is located.
2. A folder drag and drop event caused execution to take place where the drag and dropped folder's parent directory is situated.

Point 2 is where the problem came in. To rectify this we "cd" back to the directory of the .bat file in order complete our original code.

**Here is an example of the rectified *example code* of the question:**

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /b logger*.jar') do set latestjar=%%x
echo "%~dp0%latestjar%" + "%~dp0output.txt"
pause
```

**Here is the end-result of what I tried to achieve:**

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /b logger*.jar') do set latestjar=%%x
java -jar "%~dp0%latestjar%" %1 > "%~dp0output.txt"
```

**Explanation of last code segment / end-result:**
 - A folder is dropped onto a batch file in the file explorer -
 1. The code resets back to the .bat file directory
 2. We iterate through similarly named .jar files in the directory and find the most recently created one.
 3. We run the latest .jar file, with an argument which is the path of the drag and dropped folder and then we output the .jar's output to an output.txt file located in the same folder as the batch file.

Comment: `3. We run the latest .jar file, with an argument which is the path of the drag and dropped folder`. The "drag and dropped folder" would be `%~dp1`, not `%~dp0`

Comment: I think you missed the %1. Which is the location of the drag and dropped folder.

Answer (score 1):

When you "drag something" to the batch file (I assume you mean drag onto the icon of the batch file or the batch file's name in Explorer), it is executed in another working folder (There probably are no `.jar` files in `%windir%\system32`).

Solution:
make sure, the working folder is what it should be. If it should be the same folder where your batch file resides, change the working folder with:

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
```